# Font style not being applied in case of AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

I have material theme in my application and have changed the font to sans-serif-condensed application wide using the following style

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_primary</item>
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/RobotoTextViewStyle</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#000</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/color_home_screen_bg</item> 

</style>

<!--Reside menu is the base of everything . and that project inhibits the font below to be application wide.-->
<style name="RobotoTextViewStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-condensed</item>
</style>
```

Everything was working fine. Recently I had to inherit one of the activity with AppCompatActivity instead of Activity. The font has been reverted to the default and is not sans-serif.

Why does inheriting an activity from AppCompat disallow me to use the font I had mentioned in my style? I need to convert all the activities to AppCompatActivity now and I really need to get this font working.

If I specify the fontfamily attribute inside the TextView xml , then I do get the font to work. But it would be a really ugly ordeal to that in each TextView in the application

Any suggestions?

Comment: What version of app compat?

Comment: This one nick com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1

Answer (score 1):

It's a known bug for the appcompat version you are using that Text View styles are ignored. You can see the bug here:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=170476

The same bug report says it is fixed if you change to 22.2 at which point your styles should be picked up again.